# I'm trying to add new activity into my project but it gives me error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a working project now I want to add a new activity after the splash screen but it's giving me error and doesn't even build after I add new activity. Here's the error it shows when I try to build.

```
    org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
C:\Users\Naji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-23.4.0.aar\69146a3caf23a06bf4da884e96918fae\res\values\values.xml:19:5-827: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.

C:\Users\Naji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-23.4.0.aar\69146a3caf23a06bf4da884e96918fae\res\values\values.xml:19:5-827: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at 
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
C:\Users\Naji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-23.4.0.aar\69146a3caf23a06bf4da884e96918fae\res\values\values.xml:19:5-827: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''
```

Comment: Did you read the last line of the error message? What happened when you fixed that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fix this one:

```
 res\values\values.xml duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity'
```

Also please verify duplicate Attrs in my Case

```
   <declare-styleable name="CustomLay">
        <attr name="lay" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

What I change In my case, this was the issue and I have resolved it by renaming the attr name

```
    <declare-styleable name="CustomLay">
        <attr name="layName" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

Comment: I have tried changing the value but it does nothing

Comment: Then must be problem in declare-styleable in attrs.xml... please update your attrs code